# BelongToMany when primary key is another column of related model

Tags: laravel, primary-key, has-and-belongs-to-many, jenssegers-mongodb

i have two table **widget** and **page_widget**

PageWidget model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'page_id',
    'widget_codes',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by',
    'deleted_by',
    'deleted_at'
];

relation in this model:

public function widgets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Widget::class, null, 'page_widget_ids',
        'widget_codes');

}
```

widget model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'code',
    'type',
    'page_widget_ids',
    'created_by',
    'deleted_by',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

on time of store i have to sync widget_code, and i use like this:

```
$pageWidget->widgets()->sync($input['widget_codes']);
```

it's doesn't work because in widget model it default primary key considered **_id** column  and i want to give relation with **code** column

i try $primaryKey = 'code' in widget model but i'cant use this because widget model's other relation use with **_id** column.

Comment: Your model schema seems to be wrong. If you are using many to many relation, then there will be a pivot-table holding the `page_id` of page and `code` of widget model. In that case, you don't need to define `page_widget_ids` on any of your relations.

Comment: Please add the complete schema of page and widget model including `id` fields if it exists.

Comment: page_id is not primary key of page_widget table it's common column

Comment: I have posted an answer. That's the correct way to do a many to many relationship (from the docs). You have to change the table schema and create a pivot table for `sync` to work.

Answer (score 0):

When working with many-to-many relationship you need three tables `page_widget`, `page_widget_widget` and `widget`.

**PageWidget** model schema should look like this

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'created_by',
    'updated_by',
    'deleted_by',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

**Widget** model schema should look like

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'code', //primary_key
    'type',
    'created_by',
    'deleted_by',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

And the `page_widget_widget` table should have an `id`, `page_widget_id` and `widget_code` column.

After that, update your relationship to this

```
public function widgets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Widget::class, 'page_widget_widget', 'page_widget_id', 'widget_code');

}
```

Your sync function should work now.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i use jenssegers-mongodb so i dont think i need to use third table mongodb manage this in object.i only confuse about primary key,on time of sync i want 'code' column of widget as a primary key.